# gdb in tui mode doesn't display properly at some case

Tags: gdb

I use gdb with 'layout src' command and it is very useful.
by the way, I met one issue like below.

### Here is my sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   int i;

   for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){

       printf("Hello world!\n");

   }

}
```

---

And after run gdb, I run 'display' command to check i variable and run 'n' command several times.
In this case, if the command prompt is at the end of CMD window, the SRC window is displayed improperly.
If I run 'refresh' command, it shows properly but I need to run 'refresh' command everytime.

I have attached the captured image file. And I marked my point as red color square.
[gdb_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40xHt.png)

If somebody know this kind of issue, please help me to fix my issue.

Thanks.

Comment: No never seen that. But first try setting your font back to system defaults. Looks like you are using something custom.

Comment: I tried it after changing font to system default but I could still see the same issue. I attached screenshot again to make my issue more clearly. I marked my point as red color square.

Comment: Workaround: create a new window with `gnome-terminal -e "sh -c 'tty;sleep 99999'"`. Note the tty name that it prints out (e.g. `/dev/pts/1`). Run `gdb -tui`, but before starting your program, type `(gdb) tty` followed by the tty name. This will make your program output to that new blank window instead of to your gdb windows.

Comment: Hi, Mark Plotnick!

The workaround which you suggested me works well in my case.
Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the `display`, it is the `printf` in your test program.  You are seeing this [known gdb bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14332).